# Create small square Icon Button with Material UI in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

### Issue

By default, the size variant small of Button of MUI cannot work as expected when we set styles to a bit smaller.

Here is index.js:

```
<Button className="btn-delete" size="small" variant="contained"> 
   <DeleteIcon />
</Button>
```

Here is styles.scss

```
.btn-delete {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Then only the height will work.

### Expected

We need the width to work with any value as whatever we want.

Comment: You can remove the `size` props. It will work.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I never thought that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Set `min-width: 0` will resolve the problem

```
.btn-delete {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 0; <= Add this
}
```